# Will the computer ever choose not to receive the opening kickoff?

Tags: madden-12

I've now played about a dozen games of Madden 12, and I have never seen the computer choose anything but to receive the opening kickoff when they were able to choose.  I myself prefer to kick so that I get the ball to start the second half.

As such, I was wondering if the computer will ever choose to either receive or choose a side to defend (when they also have the option of choosing kick/receive).

Comment: Have you played in inclement weather yet? (Rain, snow, strong wind ...) That's the only time I'd expect it to pass on receiving; I can't remember seeing an EA AI choose to kick off more than maybe one time.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, I've played in some really strong rain before and it still chose to receive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research on the subject and am able to conclude that the computer will never elect to kick-off, they will always receive. I started a game against each NFL team and restarted until I lost the coin-flip. My findings: 100% of the time they won the coin-flip, they elected to receive. I tried it in different weather/stadiums/winds/postseason and they still choose to receive.

Answer (score -1):

The makers of the game programed it to always receive. That way it makes the game more fun and challenging.

Comment: Don't see how the computer automatically doing something even when it shouldn't could possibly make things more fun and challenging.